# How I make my count ifs function for certain worksheets work?

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I've been trying to write my own code because I can't find anything that does what i need it to. First, the code:

```
      Dim n As Long
Dim m, range1 As Range
Dim wss As Worksheet
Set range1 = wss.Range("FC2", wss.Range("FC2").End(xlDown))

  If wss.Name Like "TAPS" Then
For Each wss In Worksheets
With range1
For Each m In .Rows
If Application.CountIf(m) > 30 Then
n = n + 1
Mark1.WBAVAILABLETEXTBOX.Value = n
End If
```

What I want this code to do is find every sheet in my workbook with the word "TAPS" in the name and count every used row in the "FC2" whose cell value is over 30, and put that value in the text box.

I originally had some "Next" and "end with" in the code, but it kept popping up with errors, saying not only "end with without with," but when I delete it, it says the opposite, and the same problem with "next" regarding the "for each" aspects.

This is code I have come up with using my limited knowledge, and I am even having trouble explaining it. Any ideas for what I am doing wrong?

*EDIT FOR CLARITY* I am hoping for the final result to be the combined total from every worksheet.

Comment: What does `every used row in the "FC2"` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume OP tries to validate every used rows in the usedrange, column FC is used to determin the data range.

Please provide the detail on OP or comment if I were misunderstanding it.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim n As Long, i
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim wss As Worksheet
    n = 0
    For Each wss In Worksheets
        If wss.Name Like "*TAPS*" Then
            For i = 2 To wss.Cells(wss.Rows.Count, "FC").End(xlUp).Row
                Set Range1 = wss.Rows(i)
                If Application.CountIf(Range1, ">30") > 0 Then n = n + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Mark1.WBAVAILABLETEXTBOX.Value = n
End Sub
```

Comment: This looked correct and exactly what i needed, but when i inserted the code it said "runtime error 1004, invalid number of arguments" on line If Application.CountIf(Range1) > 30 Then n = n + 1

Comment: It's a typo. I have updated the code.

Comment: my guy! this is perfect. thank you so much. I was so damn close to getting this right, you're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in the code, and not the most suitable settling of the task. The original code would always display in the textbox the las found sheet's data. Therefore pls. check this

```
Dim n As Long
Dim range1 As Range
Dim wss As Worksheet

n = 0
For Each wss In Worksheets
  Set range1 = wss.Range("FC2", wss.Range("FC2").End(xlDown))
  If wss.Name Like "*TAPS*" Then
    n = n + Application.CountIf(range1, ">30")
  End If
Next wss
    Mark1.WBAVAILABLETEXTBOX.Value = n
    'MsgBox "Count of Cells in all sheets: " & n,,"Display result"
```

Comment: The only problem with this is I want the total amount from every worksheet COMBINED to display in a textbox

Comment: @cheese Edited the code according to your reflection. For MsgBox activate remove the comment mark `(')`

Answer (score 0):

### `Application.CountIf` on Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountTaps()
    
    Const FIRST_DATA_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "F2"
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME_CONTAINS As String = "TAPS"
    Const COLUMN_COUNTIF_CRITERIA As String = ">30"
    Const MATCH_CASE As Boolean = False
    Const DEBUG_PRINT As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod
    CompareMethod = IIf(MATCH_CASE, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, crg As Range, MatchCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, WORKSHEET_NAME_CONTAINS, CompareMethod) > 0 Then
            With ws.Range(FIRST_DATA_CELL_ADDRESS)
                Set crg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) ' "2:1048576"
            End With
            Set crg = Intersect(crg, ws.UsedRange)
            If Not crg Is Nothing Then
                MatchCount = MatchCount _
                    + Application.CountIf(crg, COLUMN_COUNTIF_CRITERIA)
                If DEBUG_PRINT Then
                    Debug.Print ws.Name, crg.Address, MatchCount
                End If
            Else
                If DEBUG_PRINT Then
                    Debug.Print ws.Name, "No Data"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    'Mark1.WBAVAILABLETEXTBOX.Value = MatchCount
    
    MsgBox "Found " & MatchCount & " cell" & IIf(MatchCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & " with a value """ & COLUMN_COUNTIF_CRITERIA & """!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

[image]

**Debug Print Results: `MATCH_CASE = False`**

```
TAPSab        $F$2:$F$11     3 
abTAPS        $F$2:$F$11     8 
aTAPSb        $F$2:$F$11     14 
bcTaPs        $F$2           14 
cdTaps        No Data
bTapsa        $F$2:$F$11     22
```

**Debug Print Results: `MATCH_CASE = True`**

```
TAPSab        $F$2:$F$11     3 
abTAPS        $F$2:$F$11     8 
aTAPSb        $F$2:$F$11     14
```